# In .NET how do I distinguish between claims identities from different authentication schemes

Tags: c#, .net, authentication

I have a .NET web app which supports two different cookie-based authentication schemes, both added via the `AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp` middleware.

It's possible for a user to be authenticated with both schemes at the same time, and there's one particular area where I need to create an authorization requirement that requires this to be the case. I also need to check the state of each claims identity.

However, at this point where I'm working with a claims principal that has multiple identities it's not possible to tell which claims identity is the product of which authentication scheme. I could infer based on the state of claims but I want to be sure.

Using raw `AddOpenIdConnect` middleware it'd be possible to intercept the claims builder via the `OnTokenValidated` event but `AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp` seems to hide this away. Is my only option to unpick `AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp` and roll my own, or is there some other way to determine which authentication scheme is responsible for a given claims identity?

Answer (score 0):

I think I worked this out. Previously I was using the following middleware wiring in my Startup:

```
authBuilder
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(
        Configuration,
        configSectionName: "AzureAdUser",
        openIdConnectScheme: "MyScheme",
        cookieScheme: "CookieUsers");
```

But by switching to a different overload I was able to implement auth events:

```
authBuilder.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(
    msIdentityOptions =>
    {
        Configuration.Bind("AzureAdUser", msIdentityOptions);

        msIdentityOptions.Events.OnTokenValidated += ctx =>
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        };
    },
    openIdConnectScheme: "MyScheme",
    cookieScheme: "CookieUsers"
);
```